# Is findViewById() not be instanced?

Tags: java, android, imagebutton

I have a question about programming in android.
When I write a activity like this:

```
package com.mathquiz;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
public class ChooseMode extends ActionBarActivity {
    private ImageButton easyButton=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.easy_button);
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose_mode);
        easyButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

}
```

The eclipse throws NullPointerException at line 4
However, if I assign "easyButton" in method onCreate, everything will be OK.

```
package com.mathquiz;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
public class ChooseMode extends ActionBarActivity {
    private ImageButton easyButton;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose_mode);
        easyButton=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.easy_button);
        easyButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

}
```

Please help me to understand this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't be "instanced" as you call it because in your first example, you haven't *set* a content view yet. Android's lifecycle methods have a specific order, that occur after the constructor is called.

The method works as expected, it just returns `null` because it has nothing to find at that current time.

Also, using an instance variable that requires using the current `Activity` as a `Context` will not work (In the below example, `this` refers to the `ChooseMode` instance).

Eg

```
public class ChooseMode extends ActionBarActivity {
    private SharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences (this);
```

Will throw a `NullPointerException` down the line when used.

Comment: So if I've got a class "Global" that extends Application, in another activity, I instance: private Global varG = (Global)getApplication();
It will throw a NullPointerException?

Comment: @user3806875 I haven't tried it. It may not due to the prerequisite that if you have an Activity, the Application should already be created. A good rule of thumb though is that you should do instantiations in `onCreate()`

Answer (score 0):

The layout is not defined on class variable definition. That's why it's a `NullPointerException`, because you haven't called `setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose_mode);` yet.

If you want to do that way, to avoid that amount of boilerplating, try [RoboGuice](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice). An example of a view could be this:

```
@ContentView(R.layout.main)
class RoboWay extends RoboActivity { 
    @InjectView(R.id.name)             TextView name; 
    @InjectView(R.id.thumbnail)        ImageView thumbnail; 
    @InjectResource(R.drawable.icon)   Drawable icon; 
    @InjectResource(R.string.app_name) String myName; 
    @Inject                            LocationManager loc; 

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        name.setText( "Hello, " + myName ); 
    } 
}
```

More examples and tutorials are [here](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/wiki).